# How to map a server-side query into an angular client-side route?

Tags: angularjs

Angular routes work well with:

```
/#/about
/#/signup/:username
```

etc.

But I was wondering if there is a way to intercept and force a server-side query into the routes model.

For example: if someone types `/signup?username=blah` then can that be intercepted and force-processed into a client-side route such as `/#/signup/blah`? And the workflow continues from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server can always do a 301 (permanent) or 307 (temporary) redirect to send the browser to a new address.

So the user will ask for one thing, get a reply that says, "try over here", and then the browser will automatically request the alternative address. You don't say what your back-end server is, but Java, Ruby on Rails, and I'm sure most other flavors of server should be able to send a redirect like that.